# Cors fails even though set up to be permissive

Tags: http, cors, genhttp

I'm running `GenHTTP` server that is setup to to have CORS permissive (so allow all):

```
var inline = Inline.Create();
inline.Add(CorsPolicy.Permissive());
```

For some reason the request still fails by CORS. For context `http://localhost:55409` is the server and `http://localhost:55309` is the client.

Options (preflight):

```
Request URL: http://localhost:55409/api/v1//metadata
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: [::1]:55409
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:55309
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 13 Jun 2022 13:05:34 GMT
Server: GenHTTP/6.3.4.0
Vary: Origin
```

This returns 204 OK.

Get:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:55409/api/v1//metadata
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Referer: http://localhost:55309/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Returns CORS error

This also feels weird as similar requests without `Authorization` header return 200 OK. The options seem to be correct in that it allows everything. Why does it fail then?

Also note that this works with the other server (more proper server running `.Net Web Api`), so client is not to blame. I think I'm missing some crucial server setup

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to specifically configure it to allow `Authorization` header, as if `*` does not include it?

```
inline.Add(new CorsPolicyBuilder().Default(new OriginPolicy(null, new List<string>() { "authorization" }, null, AllowCredentials: true, 86400u)));
```

This is the answer, but I'll mark the other answer whoever can explain why `*` does not include `Authorization` as `OPTIONS` has returned this

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

so I assume that should allow `Authorization` header as well

Comment: This is by design - `*` does not include `Authorization`. From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers): "Note that the Authorization header can't be wildcarded and always needs to be listed explicitly."

Comment: Created an issue for this: https://github.com/Kaliumhexacyanoferrat/GenHTTP/issues/302